# Old website is being loaded instead of the new one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

**PS: I'm a complete Noob at servers stuff**

So Initially I had this directory on amazon ec2, I did run the rails server using the terminal by connecting with `ssh`. Everything was working fine as expected when I hit the domain URL(I added the elastic IP in the A records of domain provider)

Now I rebuilt the website from scratch, it's on a different git repository, in order to replace the old one with the new one, I logged into ec2 via terminal, shut down the previously running rails server, cloned the new repository, navigated to the root directory and ran the server again.

when I visit the registered domain, it's showing the HTML file of the old code(no stylesheets nothing, just the index.html), if I visit `amazon_public_DNS:port_number`, I'm getting the new website loaded.

Do I need to change anything else ?

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache?

Comment: No, will try that & let you know

Comment: It also seems that you are using webrick to run the server. This might work for very small traffic numbers but is a very unstable configuration. You should look into switching to a traditional web server, such as Phusion Passenger + Apache/nginx or puma/thin (the second alternative is easier to set up)

Comment: @andreimarinescu That's definitely on my todo list, and I don't know where to get started, if you can give any link to get started that'd be great(I'd prefer Phusion Passenger). Thanks a lot for the advice :)

Comment: It's something that's actually quite easy to do, but the actual steps vary slightly depending on your environment. The way I usually deploy is using ubuntu + rvm. If this is what you are using, you can use this link: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-rails-apache-and-mysql-on-ubuntu-with-passenger (start with step 2, as you already have rails and a ruby env already running)

Comment: @vijay yes it was about clearing the browser cache :)